# java.beans.ConstructorProperties in Jackson 2

Tags: java, jackson, javabeans, lombok

My domain Objects are enhanced using [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/), which generates the java.beans [`@ConstructorProperties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html) annotation for the constructors of immutable objects.

Now in my frontend artifact, I'd like to serialize these objects to JSON using [Jackson 2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).
For Jackson 1, this could be done using [Jackson Extensions](https://github.com/joshbeitelspacher/jackson-extensions/). Is there such a solution for Jackson 2 as well or do I have to write it myself?

My main problem is that I want to keep my domain Objects frontend agnostic, so I wouldn't like to pollute them with Jackson annotations.

And no: [Java 8 parameter names](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-parameter-names) is not an option, as I am stuck with Java 7 for the time being.

Comment: Jackson 2.7 added support for constructor properties: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/905

Comment: @Thomas why don't you write this as an answer? It deserves more attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to write a similar wrapper for Jackson2 yourself.

Comment: ^^This is my colleagues making fun of me (\*sniff\*)

Comment: I did write that wrapper now, but unfortunately it's proprietary, so I can't post it here.

Answer (score 4):

Sean Patrick Floyd has already written a solution, but I am posting my solution because his is proprietary. This is a Jackson module that uses an AnnotationIntrospector to make a constructor annotated with @ConstructorProperties a jackson @JsonCreator.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.PackageVersion;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.NopAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class ConstructorPropertiesModule extends SimpleModule {

  public ConstructorPropertiesModule() {
    super(PackageVersion.VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void setupModule(Module.SetupContext context) {
    super.setupModule(context);
    context.insertAnnotationIntrospector(new ConstructorPropertiesAnnotationIntrospector());
  }

  public static class ConstructorPropertiesAnnotationIntrospector extends NopAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public boolean hasCreatorAnnotation(Annotated a) {
      if (!(a instanceof AnnotatedConstructor)) {
        return false;
      }

      AnnotatedConstructor ac = (AnnotatedConstructor) a;

      Constructor<?> c = ac.getAnnotated();
      ConstructorProperties properties = c.getAnnotation(ConstructorProperties.class);

      if (properties == null) {
        return false;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < ac.getParameterCount(); i++) {
        final String name = properties.value()[i];
        final int index = i;
        JsonProperty jsonProperty = new JsonProperty() {

          @Override
          public String value() {
            return name;
          }

          @Override
          public boolean required() {
            return false;
          }

          @Override
          public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return JsonProperty.class;
          }

          @Override
          public int index() {
            return index;
          }

        };
        ac.getParameter(i).addOrOverride(jsonProperty);
      }
      return true;
    }

  }

}
```

The module can then be registered to an object mapper to deserialize JSON using the @ConstructorProperties annotation:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
m.registerModules(new ConstructorPropertiesModule());
```

Answer (score 4):

As others stated Jackson now supports `@ConstructorProperties` - *unfortunatelly*. Because it messed up things.

The logic Jackson applies is quite unfortunate. If multiple `@ConstructorProperties` annotated constructor are present it will create the object via the one *with most parameters*. Ops. This is problem especially with Lombok which annotates *all* constructors with `@ConstructorProperties`. But anyway, this annotation is not there solely for Jackson. It makes sense to annotate every single constructor for any code inspection tool which may use this information. Lombok is right here.

Imagine following object:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor // for Jackson
@AllArgsConstructor // for builder
public class MyDto {
    private Type1 value1 = Type1.NONE;
    private Type2 value2;  
}
```

Here Jackson will always use the all-args constructor because it is annotated with `@ConstructorProperties` and has most parameters.

This also means that if you set only `value2` in your JSON object the `value1` becomes `null`. Not what you would expect.

**Conclusion:** the current behaviour (when used with Lombok or annotate more than one constructor) doesn't allow for the easy class-level default values.

**Workaround:** `@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties=true)` - but this is claimed to be deprecated soon as it's present just for java 1.5 compatibility purposes.

Comment: For what it's worth: I no longer use Lombok, as https://immutables.github.io/ is superior on almost all points. But thanks for your answer, it is a valid contribution for remaining Lombok users.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has finally been resolved in Jackson 2.7 and `@ConstructorProperties` are now supported out-of-the-box.

See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/905